# How to grep search for string but omit string from result

Tags: linux, string, bash, search, grep

I'm trying to find the expiration date of an SSL Certificate using the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect ${CERT}:443 </dev/null 2>&1 | openssl x509 -text | grep "Not After"
```

This outputs a result to the terminal in the format:

```
Not After : Apr 14 10:06:09 2018 GMT
```

How do I remove the "Not After : " part of the result and just be shown:

```
Apr 14 10:06:09 2018 GMT
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach:-

```
   openssl s_client -connect ${CERT}:443 </dev/null 2>&1 | openssl x509 -text | grep "Not After" | sed 's/Not After : //g'
```

Here I have added `| sed 's/Not After : //g'`. Now here `sed` command will search for string `Not After :` and replace it from the original string redirected to it. And final output would be:-

```
Apr 14 10:06:09 2018 GMT
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: why `/g`? If you just want to replace once, there is no need to use the global flag.

Comment: @Abhijit Pritam thanks, this worked!

Comment: why grep, sed is sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a lookbehind to get rid of it:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=Not After : ).*' <<< "Not After : Apr 14 10:06:09 2018 GMT"
Apr 14 10:06:09 2018 GMT
```

With `(?<=Not After : ).*` we are telling `grep` to print everything that comes after the fixed string "Not After : ".

Note this requires a grep with the `-P` option to load the Perl regex.

Comment: thanks for the help, but the -P flag doesn't work for me. Fixed now